# Formatting label expression with newline using Python parser?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, labeling, newline

I'm having trouble with syntax in 10.2.1, and have have tried just about everything.  With arcpy, I am attempting to access a label.expression of an ArcMap layer and modify it to:

```
lbl.expression = '[FIELDNAME] + "\n" + "taco"'
```

I can't get the "\n" part to force the rest of the expression to a new line.

Comment: This works:  lbl.expression = '[FIELDNAME] + vbnewline + "taco"'

Comment: @mfrancis... that is for vbscript in the field calculator.  The question deals with Arcpy so python.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a Windows thing, use `"\r\n"` instead.

Comment: This is a good answer to assert a new line. I built a complex label expression ArcMap would crash when label condition met: `[field1] + '\n' + [field2]`  Changing to`[field1] + '\r\n' + [field2]` works!

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing the parser was not changed to python, `'\n'` does work to force new lines within python label expressions.

[image]